# Simular quiniela en PHP

Tags: php

Quiero hacer un script en PHP que complete la realización de una quiniela al azar. Tengo el siguiente código, que haría una tabla simple de 15 filas y 3 columnas. No sé la manera de conseguir que al azar marque en cada fila un 1, X o 2. He intentado un rand(1,3), if y demás pero no logró colocarlo en su lugar correcto para que se ponga el resultado en su columna correspondiente. Es decir si sale 1, que se coloque en la columna 1 de esa fila. Alguien me podría ayudar?

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1'>";
 for ($fila=1; $fila<16; $fila++){
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($col=1; $col<4; $col++){
   echo "<td align='center'>";
 }
}
```

Si es posible, no utilizar arrays, solo if, switch, bucles o funciones.

Comment: ¿Algún motivo para no utilizar arreglos (arrays)?

Comment: Porque aún no me he documentado lo suficiente sobre los arrays y quería hacerlo sin uso de ellos, pero no pasa nada si es con array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2bc86c89bfd371a663ce0172591d6fcfd69ef9f)**

```
<?php

echo "<table border='1'>";

// creas el array con los marcadores
$marca = ["1", "x", "2"];

for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {

    // elegir resultado con rand()
    $res = $marca[rand(0,2)];

    echo "<tr>";

    // con switch ordenas cada fila del resultado $res
    switch ($res) {

        case "1":
            echo "<td>1</td><td>-</td><td>-</td>";
            break;

        case "x":
            echo "<td>-</td><td>x</td><td>-</td>";
            break;

        case "2":
            echo "<td>-</td><td>-</td><td>2</td>";
            break;
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Esta genial. ¿Pero como podría meter estos resultados en la tabla creada mía? ¿o se podría crear table con este array? ¿\n es salto de línea? Si pongo tu código pasado sin mi código de tablas lo saca todo en línea junto, he sustituido \n por <br /> para formato quiniela

Comment: Menudo crack. Impresionante. Muchas gracias :)